# Qiskit: Add a standard gate to circuit from a string

Tags: qiskit, programming

Given a circuit, if one wishes to add a gate, it is done through a line like the one below

```
mycircuit.cx(0, 1)
```

Here, we have added a control-X gate on the 0 and 1 qubits. This is probably a Python question but how can one do this given the string `'cx'` and integers `0` and `1` i.e. without manually typing them?

I tried using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string but getattr did not work for me.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.draw()
a = ('cx', 0, 1)
circ = getattr(circ, a[0])(a[1], a[2])
circ.draw()
```

Comment: How did you call `getattr`? ```getattr(mycircuit, 'cx')(0, 1)``` works for me in this case.

Comment: @VictoryOmole I have added the code I tried. The first circ.draw() works fine but the second produces an error. I expected the second time that it would draw the circuit with a gate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `AttributeError: 'InstructionSet' object has no attribute 'draw'` because `getattr` doesn't return a `QuantumCircuit`. It returns an `InstructionSet`, which doesn't have a `draw()` method.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
print(type(circuit)) # prints <class 'qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit.QuantumCircuit'>
circuit.draw()
a = ('cx', 0, 1)
circuit = getattr(circuit, a[0])(a[1], a[2])
print(type(circuit)) # prints <class 'qiskit.circuit.instructionset.InstructionSet'>
```

Removing the assignment of `circuit` to what is returned from `getatrr` should get rid of the error.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.draw()
a = ('cx', 0, 1)
getattr(circuit, a[0])(a[1], a[2])
circuit.draw()
```